# Load image in package itself

Tags: flutter, image, package

I have a "base" package in Flutter where all my shared code lives and I consume it in multiple wrapper packages "app1" etc.

I have a lot of images in the "base" package and I reference them in the `pubspec.yaml`:

```yaml
flutter:
  assets:
    - assets/images/
```

Now, I want to use it directly in the base package, but neither this

```dart
Image.asset(
  'packages/base/assets/images/test.png',
)
```

or this works.

```dart
Image.asset(
  'assets/images/test.png',
   package: 'base',
)
```

Event though the docs state that this should work like that: https://docs.flutter.dev/ui/assets/assets-and-images#from-packages

I always get this error:

```
════════ Exception caught by image resource service ════════════════════════════
The following assertion was thrown resolving an image codec:
Unable to load asset: "packages/base/assets/images/test.png".

Exception: Asset not found
```

What do I do wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A `flutter clean` of both packages helped.

Answer (score 0):

Specify file in `pubspec.yaml`

```
flutter:
  assets:
    - assets/images/test.png
```

Then use it with `package` parameter:

```
Image.asset(
  'assets/images/test.png',
   package: 'base',
)
```

Comment: Writing `assets/images/test.png` or `assets/images/` does not make a difference here.